# Disable pop up info on Version 17.3.0 Preview 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2022

After i updated my VS to Version 17.3.0 Preview 2.0, i have a pop up info from VS and i want to disable it and i don't know how(and i don't know what question to ask google). If anyone knows or have a link to a similar question i will really appreciate.

(to bad i can't put a printscreen, i don't have reputation points)

**Disable**: template (`template: "[action]/ .....`)
value    (`Ok(value: products)`)

```
[Route(template: "[action]/{category}", Name ="GetProductByCategory")]
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>>> GetProductByCategory(string category)
    {
        var products = await _productRepo.GetProductByCategory(categoryName: category);
        return Ok(value: products);
    }
```

Ty u.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Viewing inline hints" and I found it at link:

https://youtu.be/WCMb3V7nxms?t=398

For quick view (if it's disable) press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (on windows).

For permanent view: Tools → Options → Text Editor → C# → Advanced → (scroll all the way down) and Enable "Display inline parameter name hints"